# How to change old state in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of `Faq` components. When I click on a question, the answer for that particular question needs to be shown, and all other answers need to be hidden.
My problem is, I have a bunch of questions, and when I click on a question, it's showing the answer for the clicked question, but it's not hiding other answers which which were already opened.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Faq(props) {
   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
   return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => setToggle(true)}>
        <strong>{props.question}</strong></h2>
        {toggle && <p>{props.answer}</p>}   
     </div>
   )

 }

 function Faqs(props) { 
      return (
           <div>
             <Faq question={"Question 1"} answer={"answer 1"} />
             <Faq question={"Question 2"} answer={"answer 2"} />
           </div >
      )
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one of the many solutions to your problem:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Faq(props) {
   return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => { props.clickHandler(props.qid) }}>
        <strong>{props.question}</strong></h2>
        { props.toggle === props.qid && <p>{props.answer}</p> }   
     </div>
   )
 }

 function Faqs() { 
   const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState("0");

   handleClick = qid => {
     setToggle(qid);
   }

      return (
           <div>
             <Faq qid="1" question={"Question 1"} answer={"answer 1"} clickHandler={handleClick} toggle={toggle} />
             <Faq qid="2" question={"Question 2"} answer={"answer 2"} clickHandler={handleClick} toggle={toggle} />
           </div>
      )
 }
```

Instead of switching `toggle` `true` and `false`, assign an initial value of `"0"`. Assign each question a `qid` and pass it along with the `props`. The currently visible answer's question `qid` will be set in the state and answer's visibility will depend upon the current value of state matching the clicked question's `qid`.

You can also choose to hide the question's already displayed answer if it is re-clicked by checking if the clicked question's `qid` is the same as what is currently in the state and setting the `toggle` back to `"0"` (the initial state).

Feel free to change the variable name `toggle` to something like `currentQuestion` or anything that makes sense, because now we're storing the question `qid`, instead of `true` or `false`.

I know this can be optimised further but will serve as a good "working" starting point. Obviously, you won't need to repeat passing all those props in `<Faq />` because I think ultimately you'll use Array `.map()` for this.

Hope you understand this, else I will elaborate more on this.

Comment: Good solution. I forget the id and make it more complicated. thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ***setToggle*** function only sets toggle value to be ***true***.
Secondly, by clicking on a particular ***FAQ*** component will not trigger the ***onClick*** event in rest of the ***FAQ*** components.

Best solution is keeping a state variable to store which question is open at the moment in parent component and then a function to be invoked commonly for all ***FAQ*** component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Faq(props) {
   return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => props.onClick(prop.toggle === props.question ? '' : prop.question)}>
        <strong>{props.question}</strong></h2>
        {(props.toggle === props.question) && <p>{props.answer}</p>}   
     </div>
   )

 }

 function Faqs(props) {
      const [toggle, setToggle] = useState('');
      return (
           <div>
             <Faq
               question={"Question 1"}
               answer={"answer 1"}
               onClick={setToggle}
               toggle={toggle}
             />
             <Faq
               question={"Question 2"}
               answer={"answer 2"}
               onClick={setToggle}
               toggle={toggle}
             />

           </div >
      )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can work with multiple lists in optimized way. if you have many list just iterate through map instead of writing hard coding.

```
let data = [{qid:1,question: "Question 1", answer:"Answer 1"},
{qid:2,question: "Question 2", answer:"Answer 2"},
{qid:3,question: "Question 3", answer:"Answer 3"},
{qid:4,question: "Question 4", answer:"Answer 4"},
{qid:5,question: "Question 5", answer:"Answer 5"}]
function Faq(props) {
   return (
      <div>
        <h2 style={{background:'lightgrey'}} onClick={() => { props.clickHandler(props.qid) }}>
        <strong>{props.question}</strong></h2>
        { props.toggle === props.qid && <p>{props.answer}</p> }   
     </div>
   )
 }

 function Faqs() { 
   const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState("0");

   const handleClick = qid => {
     console.log(qid)
     setToggle(qid);
   }

      return (
           <div>
             {data.map(({answer,question,qid})=>
              <Faq qid={qid} question={question} 
               clickHandler={handleClick} 
               toggle={toggle} 
               answer={answer} />
              )}
           </div>
      )
 }
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kyqd3j)